# Поиск кириллицы в MySQL (Eloquent)

Tags: mysql, laravel, utf-8, eloquent

Кириллица в базе данных хранится таким образом (пример): {"ru":"\u0418\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430"}

Как мне организовать поиск кириллицы? Например, пользователь вводит часть информации в форме, а у меня ajax-ом дергается что-то вроде $cities->whereRaw("UPPER(cities.name) LIKE '%". strtoupper($args['search'])."%'");

Соответственно поиск идет по кириллическим символам, а в базе почему-то хранятся их коды

Comment: А что мешает поменять кодировку базы для нормальной работы с кириллицей? На utf8.

Comment: *Кириллица в базе данных хранится таким образом* Нет. Это таким образом где-то (чем-то) отображается то, что хранится в таблице, причём оно ещё и получено оттуда неизвестным способом. *в базе почему-то хранятся их коды* В БД коды хранятся всегда и для всего. Просто в зависимости от типа данных, кодировки и пр. они по-разному интерпретируются.

Comment: но "like %u0432%" ищет, а "like %в%" нет... Скорее всего это все из-за json_encode...